# Neo4j relationship: update a property based on its old value

Tags: merge, neo4j, relationship

When creating two relationships with the exact same properties, I want Neo4j to update a property of the relationship based on the previous value of that property. For instance, increment a counter.

Any thoughts on how I can update the following query to achieve this?

```
CREATE (p:Person {name: "Tom Hanks"})
CREATE (m:Movie {title:"You've Got Mail"});
```

```
MATCH (p:Person {name: "Tom Hanks"})
MATCH (m:Movie {title:"You've Got Mail"})
CALL apoc.merge.relationship(p, "ACTED_IN",
  {roles:['Joe Fox']},
  {created: datetime(),  counter: 0},
  m,
  {lastSeen: datetime(), counter: 1}  // Update this to something like `counter++`
)
YIELD rel
RETURN rel;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Declarative syntax

Here is the solution using the declarative form of Cypher:

```
MATCH (p:Person {name: "Tom Hanks"})
MATCH (m:Movie {title:"You've Got Mail"})
MERGE (p)-[rel:ACTED_IN {roles:['Joe Fox']}]->(m)
ON CREATE SET rel.created = datetime(), rel.counter=0
ON MATCH SET rel.lastSeen = datetime(), rel.counter=rel.counter+1
RETURN rel;
```

When the relationship is created, the counter is set to 0; otherwise it is updated.

Note: I took the declarative counterpart of the query from [Neo4j Docs](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/overview/apoc.merge/apoc.merge.relationship/), and I added the part you're interested to.

### Procedural syntax

If you are constrained or prefer using a procedural approach:

```
MATCH (p:Person {name: "Tom Hanks"})
MATCH (m:Movie {title:"You've Got Mail"})
CALL apoc.merge.relationship(p, "ACTED_IN",
  {roles:['Joe Fox']},
  {created: datetime(),  counter: -1},
  m,
  {lastSeen: datetime()}  // Update this to something like `counter++`
)
YIELD rel
SET rel.counter = rel.counter + 1
RETURN rel;
```

As you see, I set the initial counter to -1, so that at the end of the query it becomes 0; it is just an implementation detail, useful to avoid declaring a conditional statement between YIELD and RETURN.

Note: the YIELD instruction binds the created relationship with a name, in this case rel, in order to let you perform other modifications before the end of the query. See [Neo4j Docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/call/) at the second paragraph.

Comment: Thanks! Can I achieve the same/similar with `apoc.merge.relationship`?

Comment: Mainly because I'm bulk-loading data from CSV, and need the relationship type to be read for a CSV, which is not supported in the declarative form, AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

You should first fetch the relationship using `OPTIONAL MATCH` and then use the counter value from that relationship. Like this:

```
MATCH (p:Person {name: "Tom Hanks"})
MATCH (m:Movie {title:"You've Got Mail"})
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[r:ACTED_IN{roles: ['Joe Fox']}]->(m)
CALL apoc.merge.relationship(p, "ACTED_IN",
  {roles:['Joe Fox']},
  {created: datetime(),  counter: 0},
  m,
  {lastSeen: datetime(), counter: r.counter + 1}
)
YIELD rel
RETURN rel;
```

Comment: I wonder how performant this will be on a very large graph, would not fetching a relationship and then updating would result in two distinct retrievals from the graph database?

Comment: It won't have much of a negative impact on performance, because we are trying to find a link between two already fetched nodes, which internally happens via pointers. Also,  since we can index relationship properties as well, we can simply add an index on `roles` property of the relationship, which will speed the relationship look for both `OPTIONAL MATCH` and the apoc function.

Comment: But yeah this is an additional fetch.